# How to have two H4 tags using different colors

Tags: css

I am using the following style:

```
h4 {
  color: #ffffff;
}

h4 .name {
color: #cf3046;
}
```

I am using the following html

```
<h4 class="name">NAME</h4>
```

NAME is not changing color to #cf3046 but remains white. What am I doing wrong?

Thank you.

Comment: Get rid of the space between `h4` and `.name`

Comment: What that little space is communicating is `H4` elements and elements with the class `name`.  It's like the difference between `pancakes` and `pan and cakes`.  Without that space you are saying `H4` elements with the class `name`.

Answer (score 4):

```
h4.name {
    color: #cf3046;
}
```

There should be no space between h4 and .name, because they refer to the same element.

Comment: Then you have some other rule which is overriding it, or your css file is not linked, or some spelling mistake.

Comment: I fixed the problem. I simply moved the style to another existing style sheet. Both style sheets are linked, so it shouldn't matter which style sheet I add it to, should it?

Comment: If you have conflicting rules, and they both have the same specificity, the second rule will apply.